# Are 世界の一番 and 世界で一番 both correct?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, particle-の, particle-で

Are both phrases grammatically correct and how do you translate both?

> 世界**の**一番ゆうめいです
>
> 世界**で**一番ゆうめいです

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the second sentence:

> 「世界**で**一番ゆうめいです。」

is correct and it means:

> "(Something/Someone) is the best-known in the world."

「世界**の**一番ゆうめいです。」 makes no sense.

One could also say 「世界一ゆうめいです。」.

Comment: would the aforementioned sentence work in this context?
このレストランはゆうめいですか？
はい、世界の一番ゆうめいです。See for example this usage: http://yamamoto-diary.cocolog-nifty.com/blog/2009/10/post-5272.html

Comment: 世界の一番有名です is grammatically incorrect. The 日本と世界の in 日本と世界の一番長い駅名 modifies (一番長い)駅名.

Comment: ok thank you . but if it was 世界の一番ゆうめいレストランです。it would be acceptable?

Comment: 「世界の一番有名"な"レストラン」(as a title), maybe... I would say「世界で一番有名なレストランです」when I talk, though.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? "この町の一番有名なレストランだ" is legal, so why can't I swap "この町", a location, by "世界," an other location? I feel that it's like "the most famous restaurant in the world" vs "the most famous restaurant of the world" with makes sense in the adequate context.

Comment: @Axioplase 1)Who are you asking? 2)I don't think [location]の一番有名なレストランだ is incorrect. I just think [location]で一番有名なレストランだ sounds more natural. I just said [location]の一番有名だ makes no sense because it lacks the noun for the adjectival phrase [location]の to modify.

Comment: @ちょこれーと: I was asking TokyoNagoya who said "makes no sense." I think that Xで goes along with "Yだ". Here, we have "XでYだ" for X=世界 and Y=一番有名なレスタラン But we could also parse as Xだ where X=この町の一番有名なレストラン I think. Just like we can have of/in in English as well, as in my example. I'd like to know what makes "の" incorrect or non-sensical, since I understand it very well and think it's just a nuance.

Comment: @Axioplase (すみません、仰っている意味がよく分かってないかもしれませんが。)「世界で/この町で一番有名なレストランだ。」では、「世界で/この町で」は副詞的に、用言「一番有名な」を修飾します。なぜなら、「世界で/この町で」は、体言を修飾できないからです。一方、「世界の/この町の一番有名なレストランだ。」では、「世界の/この町の」は形容詞的に、体言「レストラン」を修飾します。なぜなら、「世界の/この町の」は用言を修飾できないからです。従って、「世界の/この町の一番有名なレストランだ。」は正しいですが、「世界の/この町の一番有名です。」は非文法的です。だから、TNさんは「世界の一番ゆうめいです。 makes no sense.」と言ったのです。

Comment: 英語では「is the most famous in the world」も「is the most famous of the world」もOKなのかもしれませんが、日本語では、上に示したように、無理です。

Comment: Dammit, I just realised that I invented the word "restaurant" in that sentence. Of course I see the ungrammaticality. I feel stupid...